# Total sum of all multiplied values of textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to multiply the textbox values and after multiplication sum of all answer values. Example:

```
SUM (NSP * Current Sales)
```

This program is working fine but when I change any value it adds the change not replace the values. It should replace the value of array.

And if possible, please minimize the code logic also. Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val1;
  var val2;
  var multi;
  one();
  second();
});

function one() {
  $(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
    var sumqty1 = 0;
    sumqty1 += $(this).val();
    val1 = sumqty1;
  });
}

function second() {
  $(document).on("change", ".qty2", function() {
    var sumqty1 = 0;
    var sumqty2 = 0;
    sumqty1 += $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty1').val();
    sumqty2 += $(this).val();
    val1 = sumqty1;
    val2 = sumqty2;
    mul(val1, val2);
  });
}
var arr = [];

function mul(a, b) {
  var hh;
  multi = a * b;
  arr.push(multi);
  var totalsum = 0;
  for (var i in arr) {
    var value = arr[i];
    totalsum = parseInt(totalsum, 10) + parseInt(value, 10);
    $("#totalvalue").text(totalsum);
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>NSP</th>
      <th>Current Sales</th>
      <th>Closing Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>NSP</th>
      <th>Current Sales</th>
      <th><span id='totalvalue'></span></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>Satou</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="1" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>panadol</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="2" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>131</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>disprine</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="3" disabled/></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>panadol</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="4" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>173</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: _"And if possible please minimize the code logic also"_ Why? Write readable and maintainable code and if you need to save some bytes create a minified copy with one of the many available tools out there.

Comment: Nice answer but i requested that if there is any logic to solve it in small piece of code then plz suggest me

Comment: @Andreas Succinct code can be readable, just as verbose code can be unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are continually adding new values into `arr` and there's a whole lot of shared mutable state going on here.

If there aren't that many rows in the table, you're best off just recalculating the whole total each time a value changes. Less risk of the data stepping on itself that way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.qty1, .qty2', recalculate);

  function getTotal() {
    return $('#myTable tr')
      .toArray()
      .map($)
      .map(function (row) { 
        return row.find('.qty1').val() * row.find('.qty2').val(); 
      })
      .filter(function (val) { return !Number.isNaN(val); })
      .reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
  }

  function recalculate() {
    $("#totalvalue").text(getTotal());
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>NSP</th>
      <th>Current Sales</th>
      <th>Closing Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>NSP</th>
      <th>Current Sales</th>
      <th><span id='totalvalue'></span></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>Satou</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="1" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>panadol</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="2" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>131</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>disprine</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="3" disabled/></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>panadol</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="4" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>173</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it right now, you're adding new elements to the array in the order they're created, which doesn't allow you to access them later to change them because they could be stored in any order.

The code below saves each value in the array based on the value of `val1` so that each element has a designated place in the array.  Because of that, you can update any of the values when they are changed, like so:

```js
var arr = [];

function one() {
  $(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
    var sumqty1 = $(this).val();
  });
}

function second() {
  $(document).on("change", ".qty2", function() {
    var val1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty1').val();;
    var val2 = $(this).val();
    mul(val1, val2);
  });
}

function mul(a, b) {
  arr[a - 1] = a * b;
  var totalsum = 0;
  for (var i in arr) {
    var value = arr[i];
    totalsum = parseInt(totalsum, 10) + parseInt(value, 10);
    $("#totalvalue").text(totalsum);
  }
  console.log(arr);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  one();
  second();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>NSP</th>
      <th>Current Sales</th>
      <th>Closing Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>NSP</th>
      <th>Current Sales</th>
      <th><span id='totalvalue'></span></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>Satou</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="1" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>panadol</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="2" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>131</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>disprine</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="3" disabled/></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>panadol</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty1" value="4" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty2" value="" /></td>
      <td>173</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I also took out some unnecessary code, including:

- The `hh` declaration (since that variable isn't used) in your `second()` function
- a couple of extraneous lines in your `one()` function
- the `multi` variable
- the `sumqty1` and `sumqty2` variables (you can just use `val1` and `val2`)

Your `val1` and `val2` variables didn't need to be global, since you are only using them in one function and passing them as parameters to another.

You could also remove the `one()` function if you want, since those values seem to be static -- but I'm not sure if you allow that value to be changed in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Id say something like:

```
$(".qty1, .qty2").on("change", function(){
    var qty2 = $(".qty2"),
        total = 0;
    $(".qty1").each(function(ind){
        total += $(qty2[ind]).val() * $(this).val();
    })
    $("#totalvalue").text(total)
})
```

Added at the end of the document.

Edited a little